# Reason for Cache Manifest: Application Cache Error event: Resource fetch failed (2)

Tags: google-chrome, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

My manifest file was working fine until this morning and I now keep getting the following error in chrome Version 36.0.1985.143 m

```
Creating Application Cache with manifest https://localhost/static/app/cache.manifest dashboard:1
Application Cache Checking event dashboard:1
Application Cache Downloading event dashboard:1
Application Cache Progress event (0 of 192) https://localhost/static/app/images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png dashboard:1
Application Cache Error event: Resource fetch failed (2) https://localhost/static/app/images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png
```

The resource is there when i follow through the link. But i can not find anywhere that details what the (2) means (seen lots for -1 but nothing for (2)) . I have a valid certificate for https as this was one of my pitfalls when first dealing with the cache manifest so do not believe that this is the issue.

Here is my manifest (it is generated by grunt and seems to be valid)

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# This manifest was generated by grunt-manifest HTML5 Cache Manifest Generator
# Time: Wed Aug 20 2014 10:37:07 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)

CACHE:
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-Bold.eot
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-Bold.otf
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-Bold.svg
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-Bold.ttf
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-Bold.woff
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-BoldIta.eot
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-BoldIta.otf
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-BoldIta.svg
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-BoldIta.ttf
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-BoldIta.woff
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-Light.eot
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-Light.otf
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-Light.svg
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-Light.ttf
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-Light.woff
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-LightIta.eot
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-LightIta.otf
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-LightIta.svg
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-LightIta.ttf
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-LightIta.woff
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-Medium.eot
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-Medium.otf
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-Medium.svg
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-Medium.ttf
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-Medium.woff
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-MediumIta.eot
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-MediumIta.otf
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-MediumIta.svg
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-MediumIta.ttf
fonts/JohnstonITCStd-MediumIta.woff
images/ajax-loading.gif
images/angle-purpure.png
images/angle-red.png
images/angle-yellow.png
images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png
images/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png
images/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png
images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png
images/apple-touch-startup-image-2048x1496.png
images/background.jpg
images/bathroom.png
images/blocker-white.png
images/blocker.png
images/bottom-arrow.png
images/box-shadow-bg.png
images/btn-arrow-bottom.png
images/btn-close.png
images/btn-counter.png
images/btn-left-panel.png
images/btn-sidebar-left-open.png
images/btn-top-panel.png
images/calendar5.png
images/checkbox-big.gif
images/checkbox.gif
images/close-lightbox-button.png
images/copy-icon-dark.png
images/copy-icon.png
images/copy_button.png
images/correct8.png
images/customer_photo_card.jpg
images/customer_photo_lightbox.jpg
images/customer_photo_profile.jpg
images/customer_photo_sidebar.jpg
images/customer_photo_smallcard.jpg
images/dashboard-tab-active-bg.png
images/dashboard-tab-active-gray-bg.png
images/decor-1.jpg
images/decor-2.jpg
images/decor-3.jpg
images/decor-4.jpg
images/decor-arrow-bottom-gray.png
images/decor-item-bg-purpure.png
images/decor-item-bg-red.png
images/decor-item-bg-yellow.png
images/decor-item-bg.png
images/delete-icon-16x16.png
images/delete-icon-24x24.png
images/delete-icon-32x32.png
images/delete-icon-48x48.png
images/delete-icon-64x64.png
images/dialog-decor-purpure.png
images/dialog-decor-red.png
images/dialog-decor-yellow.png
images/dialog-decor.png
images/dialog-overlay.png
images/flag_icon_de.png
images/flag_icon_fr.png
images/flag_icon_it.png
images/flag_icon_uk.png
images/flight-big.png
images/flight-small.png
images/flight.png
images/form-dialog-bg.png
images/general_user_card.jpg
images/general_user_card.png
images/general_user_lightbox.jpg
images/general_user_profile.jpg
images/general_user_sidebar.jpg
images/general_user_smallcard.jpg
images/help-bg.png
images/ico-contact-group-1-small.jpg
images/ico-contact-group-1.jpg
images/ico-contact-group-2-small.jpg
images/ico-contact-group-2.jpg
images/icon-1.png
images/icon-2.png
images/icon-attention.png
images/icon-delete-big.png
images/icon-delete.png
images/icon-dragable.png
images/icon-mail-small.png
images/icon-mail.png
images/icon-minus.png
images/icon-mobile-small.png
images/icon-mobile.png
images/icon-pdf-small.png
images/icon-pdf.png
images/icon-phone-small.png
images/icon-phone.png
images/icon-plus.png
images/icon-power.png
images/icon-remove-big.png
images/icon-remove.png
images/icon-user.png
images/icon.png
images/icons-bg.png
images/icons-big-bg.png
images/icons-slider-arrow-left.png
images/icons-slider-arrow-right.png
images/icons-small-bg.png
images/icons-xsmall-bg.png
images/info6.png
images/line25.png
images/lock-close-icon.png
images/lock-open-icon.png
images/logo-small.gif
images/logo.png
images/outing.png
images/radio-big.png
images/remove11.png
images/search28.png
images/select-arrow-bg.png
images/select-dropdown-bg.png
images/select-sep-bg.gif
images/sep-1-bg.gif
images/signal_disabled_big.jpg
images/signal_disabled_small.jpg
images/signal_pause_big.jpg
images/signal_pause_small.jpg
images/signal_waiting_validation_big.jpg
images/signal_waiting_validation_small.jpg
images/sleep.png
images/sort27.png
images/sub-header-bg.png
images/sub-header-bottom-bg.png
images/temp-1.jpg
images/temp-10.gif
images/temp-2.jpg
images/temp-3.jpg
images/temp-4.jpg
images/temp-5.jpg
images/temp-6.jpg
images/temp-7.jpg
images/temp-8.png
images/temp-9.jpg
images/time-line-bg.gif
images/time-line-sep-bg.gif
images/tooltips-bg.png
images/top-arrow-gray.png
images/top-arrow-white.png
images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png
images/ui-bg_flat_0_eeeeee_40x100.png
images/ui-bg_flat_55_ffffff_40x100.png
images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png
images/ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png
images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_f6f6f6_1x100.png
images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_25_0073ea_1x100.png
images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_50_dddddd_1x100.png
images/ui-icons_0073ea_256x240.png
images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png
images/ui-icons_666666_256x240.png
images/ui-icons_ff0084_256x240.png
images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png
css/app-styles.min.css
javascripts/app/router_dashboard.js
javascripts/app/router_profile.js
javascripts/app/router_settings.js
javascripts/app/router_test.js
javascripts/distro/app-dashboard-built.js
javascripts/distro/app-profile-built.js
javascripts/distro/app-settings-built.js
javascripts/dispatch.js

NETWORK:
*
```

So my question is does anyone know what the error means and how it can be fixed?

Edit: This problem disappeared on it's own after a day but I do not know what caused it or what I might have done to fix it the only action i did do was clear my flags in chrome (experimental features) but this did not have an immediate effect to remove the error

Here are some other facts about this error

- Other developers with the same code did not see this error (same version of chrome) (I know this makes for a bad SO question if it is not reproducible but I have no idea what the error even means hence the main reason for asking)
- This happened on both the development version and production version (development version using Apache and production using nginx)
- This did not happen to other websites that I know to use appcache (deezer.com)

edit: as of 04/09/2017 i still have never found the root cause for this error or seen it again actually

Comment: I have the same situation. My manifest cache randomly stopped working for me today.

Comment: I have the same problem as described. Is there any chance to solve this problem or do I have to wait until it resolves itself magically like described by the thread starter?

Comment: So far I still have not found the one thing that cleared it and since asking this question I have never reproduced the error to confirm what works. Black magic it seems is the best way forward :(

Answer (score 11):

I faced the same problem and found two causes:

- I was using Chrome in incognito mode (it should be used in the normal mode)
- My server was returning a 301 redirect instead of a 200 OK (it should return a 200 OK)

I was able to solve the problem by fixing the above two.

Comment: Me too, but why is incognito the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also experiencing the same on Chrome/36.0.1985.143 in Windows and the latest Chrome for OSX.

Looking in the access logs, for the file in question the server is returning a status code 200 (OK) rather than a 403 (Not Found)

Based on what you and I are seeing, I don't believe the file referenced in the "Resource fetch failed (2)" message is relevant.

We are seeing this on the very first item as its hit.

In my case I already expect the appcache to be up to date, and Apache should be returning HTTP status code 304 (Not Modified) so the Chrome knows that file is up to date.

So I think we may both have reached a limit, and what we are seeing is a side effect.

Quince, your AppCache Manifest looks valid. 
I'd like to get to the bottom of this also, can you provide further details please?
I'm interested to know the total sizes of the files you've listed in the manifest above.

Comment: Total size before being gzipped to be sent is 4Mb (and some very small change) the largest of these being the fonts. I am actually no longer seeing this error but left the question here as i really want to know what caused this in the first place. i have added a few more details to more question about what i saw that might have a factor

Comment: Maybe my change on chrome://flags/ did do something but any fix i did I would have thought to be instantly noticeable but this was not the case when resting them all to default. About the limit when i look in chrome://appcache-internals/ I was well below a couple of sites (like deezer) which had 9.7Mb

Comment: In my case, the total size of my files is not even 1mb and have the same problem as @Quince.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem as well as you may noticed in my previous comments. I ended up fixing it just by completely restarting Chrome (I tend to let both my laptop and Chrome always running). Once I did it the problem went away.

Comment: It weird as I also restarted chrome but didn't see the problem disappear straight away, it was not until the day after that it went. strange.

Comment: No, I couldn't find any info related to the issue. The weirdest thing is that I haven't made any deploy to my site for days and just for yesterday was having that problem until I restarted Chrome.

Comment: Restarting Chrome also resolved this exact issue for me.

Before doing that I thought I would try clearing the appcache for my site. I visited chrome://appcache-internals/ to do that, and Chrome told me "No available Application Caches", which was not what I expected at all.

After restarting Chrome I still had the same "No available Application Caches" message, but my appcache site loaded up fine, and could then be found at chrome://appcache-internals/

I'm wondering if, in fact, Chrome spontaneously lost all appcaches I had in the browser at the time the fault occurred.